# How to use threading to call a repetitive process in .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading

In my website, I need to do a repetitive task which should not affect the main activity and performance of the website.

So I think I need to use threading. I am new into threading in .Net. How to use threading is .NET?

Any tutorials or reference to any article would be a great help.

Comment: You can do this by threading within an Asp.Net website, but it might be much easier to create a separate windows service for the background process.

Comment: (General note to readers: I removed the request for resources/tutorials from this old question, as that kind of question is off-topic, but I changed my mind because the accepted answer is little more than a list of links. This question would be closed if asked today, but it may escape community moderation because of its age).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial on how to do [multi-threaded applications in .NET](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/) a simple way to get work done on another thread is to use a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker).

When working with heavy tasks on other threads over the web, you might want to initiate the request using Ajax and then "poll" for answers.

There's an article over at MSDN: [Use Threads and Build Asynchronous Handlers in Your Server-Side Web Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/june/using-threads-to-build-asynchronous-handlers-in-server-web-code), it's a bit old but I think you can get a basic understanding by reading it.

Comment: The first link (at `www.yoda.arachsys.com`) produces a 404. Would you repair or remove?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to make use of multithreading in .NET.
As already mentionned, you can use a BackgroundWorker, but you can also make use of [Task based Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming), which is the recommended way since the TPL is available in .NET

This means that you can offload work that needs to be done on another thread as simple as

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
```

[This](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html) article from Stephen Cleary is also an interesting read.  It compares BackGroundWorker with TPL.

Also, keep in mind that if you execute long-running tasks in asp.net, your requests may take a long time to complete.  It might be better to execute long-running tasks in another service, like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this in an ASP.NET application is using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. This ensures that the background task will shutdown gracefully when the IIS application is recycled, machine shut down or something like that.

Call this once somewhere in startup of the application:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(RunInBackground);
```

And then implement a method like this:

```
private async Task RunInBackground(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Repetetive task

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
}
```

You could also use `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject` and do things more manually. You would gain some control, but will be less simple.